# Logs in series results from ARMA(1,2,1) to AR(3,2)

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am working on this dataset.

```
library(Quandl)
bitcoin <- Quandl("BITSTAMP/USD",type = "xts")
bitcoin.price <- bitcoin[,"last"]
```

When I do **NOT take logs** since they have increasing variance, the model is:
ARMA(1,2,1)
with pic:
[image]

*on the other hand*, if I **take logs**, I have:

[image]

Does this make sense?
Why taking logs remove the MA component?

Comment: why don't you post this "simple series" . You night also look at http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers

Comment: yes Sure I will do it.

Comment: AR and MA have competing behaviors: MA corrects slight over differentiating and AR corrects slight under differentiating. See [Identifying the numbers of AR or MA terms in an ARIMA model](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411arim3.htm#signatures) for details.